# How can i remove Toggle side menu button from splash screen in android

Tags: android

I have to remove "THDC" & "icon" from splash screen and main screen from action bar. Please see image of side menu & Splash screen.  i am attaching code below.
How can i remove Toggle side menu button from splash screen.
please help me to remove.

[Main Screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh5cB.png)

[Splashscreen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L42UT.png)

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    //  drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adater1;


    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    // data of json url
    private static final String url = "http://milagro.in/wip/apps/n/THDC2.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Enabling Up / Back navigation
        //actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("tata_project_name"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("project_logo_url"));
                                movie.setParkingUrl(obj.getString("parking"));
                                movie.setPowerbackupUrl(obj.getString("powerbackup"));
                                movie.setFitnessUrl(obj.getString("fitness"));
                                movie.setLiftUrl(obj.getString("lift"));
                                movie.setParkUrl(obj.getString("park"));
                                movie.setSecurityUrl(obj.getString("security"));
                                movie.setSwimmingUrl(obj.getString("swimming"));
                                movie.setTypology(obj.getString("project_Typology"));
                                movie.setPrice(obj.getString("price"));
                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
        //addListenerOnButton();
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Profile
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // About
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Emi Calculator
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Currency Converter
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // PayInstallments/EMI
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // Social Feed
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
        // Feedback
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
        //Settings
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adater1 = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adater1);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.menu, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                mDrawerList.bringToFront();
                mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
//          displayView(0);
        }
    }
    /*@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
    }*/
    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }




    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Profile();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new About();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new EMICalculator();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new CurrencyConverter();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new PayInstallment();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new SocialFeed();
                break;
            case 6 :
                fragment =new Feedback();
                break;
            case 7:
                fragment =new Settings();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }



    public void bottomMenuClick(View v)
    {
        int pos = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());

        switch (pos)
        {
            case 1: // enquiry screen
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Enquiry.class));
                break;
            case 2: // contact screen
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Contact.class));
                break;
            case 3: // Instant Call Back screen
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CallBack.class));
                break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }


/*  public void menuClick(View v)
    {
        dLayout.bringToFront();

        menu_lay.bringToFront();
        topLay.bringToFront();

        dLayout.requestLayout();
        dLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        dLayout.openDrawer(listView);
    }*/
```

splashscreen.java

public class SplashActivity extends Activity
{

```
protected int _splashTime = 2000;
int secondsDelayed = 1;
ImageView img;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);



   img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
   assert getActionBar() != null;
    getActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);

    View mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
    mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    //img.setImageResource(R.drawable.splashscreen);


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            Intent HomeScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(HomeScreen);
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            finish();

        }
    }, secondsDelayed * _splashTime);



}
```

}

Androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:name="info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name">


        </activity>


        <activity
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:name=".util.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ProjectScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

[image: Beforesplashimage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `onCreate()` to the following:

```
assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
getSupportActionBar().hide();
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

View mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

where `fullscreen_content` is the ID of your parent layout.

eg.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_splash_bk"
    tools:context="com.abc.xyz.Splash">

    // content of splash

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Zuin kadva solves splash screen problem But it still coming in main sceen page .

Comment: Use the same `onCreate()` syntax for `MainActivity.java` also. PS: Please annotate my name properly!

Comment: This removes side menu toggle if i declare in main activity same . I want Side menu screen toggle button in main screen .

Comment: OK. Try this: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);` in `onCreate()`

Comment: yes it came . But Now Icon is coming in main screen . How can i remove it ?

Comment: Good. You are halfway through, Now try: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);` Please up-vote my answer if it helped you.

Comment: yes i did but not one problem is if i am clicking side menu screen fragment then particular title is not setting in top of screen while it was setting earlier.

Comment: In `MainActivity.java` under`private class SlideMenuClickListener` in `setTitle(CharSequence title)` add `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);`

Comment: Thank you . Now one more problem is coming before splash screen one screen is coming which is setting of icon and title . Why it is coming Could you please tell me is there any solution for same ?

Comment: In `SplashScreen.java` under `onCreate()` add: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);`

Comment: No It did not work . It is still coming before splash screen.

Comment: If `SplashScreen.java` is your starting activity, how can another activity appear before splash?

Comment: see what i have uploaded image it is coming before splash .it is coming with icon & title only for a second then splash screen is coming . I am unable to get why ?

Comment: Can you post the updated code for `SplashScreen.java`

Comment: Why is `SplashScreen.java` extending `MainActivity.java`? It should extend `AppCompactActivity` See if that helps.

Comment: @user6313669 please look at the answer i have posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:name=".util.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Replace in manifest

```
<activity
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:name=".util.SplashActivity"
                android:theme="@style/myStyle"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
                <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>

            </activity>
```

Add style in style.xml in values

```
<style name="myStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    </style>
```

Comment: replace got error like
Error:(30, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar').

Comment: still Error:(173) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something is wrong in the order in which the code executes.

**SplashActivity.java**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompactActivity {

    protected int _splashTime = 2000;
    int secondsDelayed = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    

        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Intent HomeScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(HomeScreen);
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                finish();
            }
        }, secondsDelayed * _splashTime);

    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
android:name="com.abc.xyz.SplashActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

See if that helps.